# dig doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.10, works in 12.04 in the same network

Tags: 12.04, networking, dns, 14.10, router

I'm having an issue when trying to use dig at one of my computers running Ubuntu 14.10 Desktop 64 bit. The same works in Ubuntu 12.04 both at separate physical machine and running inside VMWare (utopic being the host).

```
dig ubuntu.com
; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-4.3-Ubuntu <<>> ubuntu.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I thought that maybe this has something to do with dnsmasq, so I disabled it in NetworkManager's config file (and restarted service). Finally I found out, that

```
dig @192.168.1.1 ubuntu.com
```

(192.168.1.1 being router's IP) doesn't work either in utopic, while it's working in precise. nslookup, browser, various programmes using Internet and e.g. dig @8.8.8.8 work without any issues. However, when I connect to other network (like using AndroidAP from my phone) everything works in utopic too.

Is there a way in which I could find what's making my Ubuntu 14.10 installation not compatible with my router's DNS?

Answer (score 0):

Right now I had the same problem on fresh installed 14.10 64-bit.  Quick Internet research gives me nothing therefore I decide to re-install package before to go further. Surprisingly the dig starts working after that.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall dnsutils
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. Eventually I solved that by editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` and adding `prepend domain-name-servers ISP's DNS IP,8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4;`. Maybe that's not optimal, but works for now.

Comment: I am sorry to hear this. You could get default DNS servers of your provider via DCHP and use them in  dhclient.conf `nmcli dev list iface wlan0 | grep DNS` Or/and you could install dnsmasq in order to have local the light DNS server and avoid delays for ns1.google ns2.google `sudo apt-get install dnsmasq`